# Laravel 5.4 required_with doesn't works with alpha_dash and min

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

That's my validation code:

```
'old_password' => 'max:255|required_with:new_password|old_password',
'new_password' => 'max:255|required_with:old_password|min:6|alpha_dash',
```

I've got alpha_dash and min:6 validation fails if both fields is empty. How can I fix it?

old_password is a custom rule

```
Validator::extend('old_password', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
  if( $value == ''){
      return true;
  } else {
      return \Hash::check($value, request()->user()->password);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the `old_password` rule supposed to do? Because it doesn't exist in Laravel.
By the way, you have no reason to restrict what characters can be used in a password and how long it has to be, since the value HAS to be hashed before being stored in the DB.

Comment: old_password is my custom rule. Even if I remove alpha_dash, I'll get  min:6 validation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `min:6` and the `alpha_dash` rules don't know about the `required_with:old_password` rule and that it failed when the `old_password` field isn't present. That's why they fail too.

Try to go for an extended `sometimes` rule for your new_password field. A more detailed description can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16646#issuecomment-268838997).

```
$validator->sometimes('newPassword', 'newPassword', function(){
  return ! request('oldPassword');
})
```